# Python Multiple Assignment with Panda Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I would like to fill 2 destination pandas columns at once for performance reasons.
A sample value from the source column is '42844 - News - BENL'. I need to extract '42844' and 'News'. Additional values can be ignored.

```
df["_site_id"], df["_site_name"], rest = df["website"].apply(lambda x: x.split(" - ", 2))
```

I tested this code and i get a 'ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 3)'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us do `str.split`

```
df["website"].str.split(" - ", 2, expand=True)
#df=df.join(df["website"].str.split(" - ", 2, expand=True).rename(columns={0:'_site_id', 1:'_site_name'}))
```

Comment: Thanks, no more errors but column _site_id is always 0 and _site_name is always 1

Answer (score 3):

For vectorized string operations in pandas you have `str`. So instead you can use `Series.str.split`. Also for this assignment to work you have to first "expand" the resulting list into `n` new columns, so set `expand=True`:

```
df["_site_id"], df["_site_name"], _ = df.website.str.split(' - ', 2, expand=True)
```

Which could also be done by indexing on a list of columns and splatting on the lhs as:

```
*df[['_site_id', '_site_name']], _ = df.website.str.split(' - ', 2, expand=True)
```

---

*Note*: For multiple assignment to work there must be `3` columns as a result from splitting `website`, otherwise you'll get a `ValueError` saying that there are not enough values to unpack.